# Android : Configuring Appwidget size at create time

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

According to the documentation it should be possible to configure the size of an App Widget using a configuration activity
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#Configuring

> If you would like the user to configure settings when he or she adds a new App Widget, you can create an App Widget configuration Activity. This Activity will be automatically launched by the App Widget host and allows the user to configure available settings for the App Widget at create-time, such as the App Widget color, size, update period or other functionality settings.

I can't find any examples on how to do this, has anyone got any ideas?

Thanks!

Ash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may not be possible at the moment to do exactly what you want.

I think the solution is to create separate providers just for the different sizes (4x1, 3x1, 4x2, etc.), but the content displayed is up to the developer. After selecting the widget (size) a Configuration Activity can be shown where the user can then select what content he wants.

- [how to add multiple widgets in one app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570004/how-to-add-multiple-widgets-in-one-app)

For an example of a working manifest file with multiple providers see:

- http://code.google.com/p/transdroid/source/browse/trunk/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Thanks Justin, I think that is the probably the only way of doing things.  The docs are quite misleading.

Comment: +1 - A number of things are misleading with the Android Docs.