# How to update widgets of different sizes?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-manifest, android-appwidget

My app has supports multiple size widgets per the scheme outlined here  [how to add multiple widgets in one app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570004)

It has a single abstract BaseWidgetProvider class that handle all the widgets. It is then subclassed by empty WidgetProvider1/2/3/4 classes (one per size) that are listed in the Android Manifest and everything works just fine. The registration in the manifest looks like this (typical for 1..4)

```
<receiver
    android:name=".widget.MyWidgetProvider4"
    android:label="My Widget size 4" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action  
            android:name="my.domain.BaseWidgetProvider.UPDATE_WIDGET" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/my_widget_info4" />
    </receiver>
```

My question is about sending an intent from the app to update the widgets with new data. I could not find a way to send a single intent for all 4 providers and am currently sending 4 seperate intents each time

```
for (Class cls : BaseWidgetProvider.WIDGET_PROVIDER_CLASSES) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(mApp.context(), cls);
   intent.setAction(BaseWidgetProvider.UPDATE_WIDGET);
       this.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

where

```
public static final Class[] WIDGET_PROVIDER_CLASSES = new Class[] {
    WidgetProvider4.class,
    WidgetProvider1.class,
    WidgetProvider2.class,
    WidgetProvider3.class      
};
```

1. Is this the best way to send an update intent to all widget sizes (note that typically the user has only zero or one widgets)?
2. Is there a reasonable way to send only a single intent?
3. Is there a way to have a single receiver that will update widget instances of all four sizes?

Note that the base provider class does not care about the widget size and does exactly the same for all sizes. The only difference is the initial widget size on the user's screen. If the user resizes the widget (e.g. using Launcher Pro), it works just fine.

Comment: I was trying to follow the same link for multiple size widget, but i could not get the idea of how to implement the base class. I am just a beginner in android as well as java. So, it would be very helpful if you could post all your solution, or the steps you followed. It would be very helpful for me as well as other beginners out there who are stuck in this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an intent filter with one intent action into the declarations of all of your widget providers in Manifest file, e.g.:

```
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="my.domain.blablabla.MY_SUPER_INTENT_TO_UPDATE_ALL" />
    </intent-filter>
```

And then just send this intent from your application as broadcast.
In this case the intent will be handled by all your widget providers.

Comment: This works, thanks. I removed the target class from the intent and all the widget providers now respond to the same intent. Is there a way to have a single receiver for all the widget sizes? The handling of the intent is the same for all of them so there is no point to compute it 4 times.