# A couple of different widgets in the same app

Tags: java, android, widget, android-widget, android-appwidget

I want to create three different widgets with different sizes. I didn't find any tutorial, except this question [how to add multiple widgets in one app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570004/how-to-add-multiple-widgets-in-one-app) and I went this way.

Here is question, because later you will see long wall of the code.

When APPWIDGET_UPDATE is fired, in some way my widget gets update three times. I debugged that and found that overriden method `updateRemoteView()` launches three times from the three subclasses. How to launch it just from one class?

I've added three different receivers in to the Manifest:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".DaysWidgetSmall"
        android:label="@string/small_widget_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/small_widget_provider" />
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name=".DaysWidgetMedium"
        android:label="@string/medium_widget_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/medium_widget_provider" />
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name=".DaysWidgetLarge"
        android:label="@string/large_widget_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/large_widget_provider" />
    </receiver>
```

Next I've created one base class and three subclasses:

Base One (parts of it):

```
@Override
public void onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId, Bundle newOptions) {
    super.onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId, newOptions);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 2000);

    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 2000, pendingIntent);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

    if (intent.getAction().equals(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE)) {

        if (extras != null) {
            int[] widgetIds =
                    appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(
                            new ComponentName(
                                    context, DaysWidgetSmall.class
                            ));

            for (int appWidgetId : widgetIds) {
                RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), getLayout());
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
                        context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                updateRemoteView(views, sharedPreferences, appWidgetId);
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
            }

            widgetIds =
                    appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(
                            new ComponentName(
                                    context, DaysWidgetMedium.class
                            ));

            for (int appWidgetId : widgetIds) {
                RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), getLayout());
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
                        context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                updateRemoteView(views, sharedPreferences, appWidgetId);
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
            }

            widgetIds =
                    appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(
                            new ComponentName(
                                    context, DaysWidgetLarge.class
                            ));

            for (int appWidgetId : widgetIds) {
                RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), getLayout());
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
                        context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                updateRemoteView(views, sharedPreferences, appWidgetId);
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
            }
        }
    }
}

public abstract int getLayout();

public abstract void updateRemoteView(RemoteViews views, SharedPreferences prefs, int id);
```

And here is short implementations of the one of the three classes (currently they are different by returning layouts, but later I want to expand this):

```
public class DaysWidgetSmall extends DaysWidget {

    @Override
    public int getLayout() {
        return R.layout.small_widget;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateRemoteView(RemoteViews views, SharedPreferences prefs, int id) {
        int current = prefs.getInt(PREFS_COUNT_NAME + id, 0);
        prefs.edit().putInt(PREFS_COUNT_NAME + id, ++current).apply();
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.update, current + "");
    }
}
```