# Android Studio: widget layout visual development

Tags: android, layout, widget

How can I control widget's space in Android Studio when developing a widget layout?
Let's say I want to build 3×1 (3 squares width and 1 square height) widget - so how can I visually control that my widget's content fits into this given size?

Horizontal and vertical rulers help little, really((.

Is it possible? What is the best strategy?

Thank you!

Comment: you can Programmatically set the size of a widget layout like this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6798938/2960945

Comment: Nope, I want to see what is happening on the screen when putting controls on my widget and watch them not to go beyond the borders (3×1 size)

Comment: This could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570004/how-to-add-multiple-widgets-in-one-app